# Expand key to size of plaintext

Tags: cryptography

I'm taking a cryptology course, and one thing that popped up as an idea was the following:

Can't one take a "master" key, and generate a key that is as big as the plaintext, to encrypt the plaintext and thereby having perfect secrecy?

The strength of course would depend on the size of the masterkey, but that's the case with every crypto-system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a master key to generate what is called a "keystream" the size of the plaintext, and XOR it with the plaintext to encrypt it.  This is what we call a stream cipher, and examples are RC4 and Salsa20.

No, this does not provide perfect security.  Claude Shannon demonstrated in 1949 that you cannot have information theoretic perfect secrecy without a random key the same length as the plaintext.  (As many possible keys in the keyspace as plaintexts in the message space.)   The use of a small key means that there are necessarily fewer keys than plaintexts, and expanding them to the length of the message using a pseudo-random generator does not change this.  Use the same key twice, get the same keystream twice.  Because of this, a stream cipher cannot offer the perfect secrecy of a one time pad, where the key is both truly random, and the length of the message.

Answer (score 0):

Under certain conditions, yes.

1. The key is as large as the plaintext.
2. The key is truly random.
3. The key is only used once.

This is known as a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad), and when the above conditions are met, is completely unbreakable.  They aren't used very much in practice because good algorithmic encryption is almost as secure, and much easier to work with.

Comment: That doesn't meet the conditions of the questions however, which specifically asked about expanding a small key.